# Decrement 2 in For C++

Tags: c++

I decrement a number twos, but over all I can do FOR 1.

How I can do?
Here is the basic FOR

```
for (i=n;i>0;i--)
```

But decrement 1.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int n,i,e;
char op;
cout<<"ingrese un numero para realizar las operaciones descriptas a continuacion :"<<endl;
cin>>n;
cout<<"Su numero es : "<<n<<endl;
cout<<"Este programa mostrara una lista de los numeros pares menores a su numero.\n\n\tEn que forma desea ver la lista? "<<endl;
cout<<"\t \t a)De manera creciente"<<endl<<"\t \t b)De manerda decreciente "<<endl;
cin>>op;
if (op=='a') {
    if (n%2==0){
        cout<<"El numero que usted ingreso es par "<<endl;
        for (i=n;i>0;--i) {
            cout<<i<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or trying to do.

Comment: Don't understand the question, but you might be after `i-=2`

Answer (score 5):

Why can't you just do this?

```
for (i = n; i > 0; i -= 2) 
{
}
```

Comment: YEAHH!!!!! YEAHH!!!!! :)))))) SORRY :( im amateur! :(

Comment: @EmanuelMathiasCanova Hey. That's not an excuse. Please read a comprehensive C++ tutorial before wasting our time. Thanks.

Comment: @EmanuelMathiasCanova: If you like an answer, check it.

Comment: @H2CO3:  You could have said something to that effect a little less abrasively.

Answer (score 0):

here in this `for` loop

```
for( int i = n; i>0; i--){
// i = i-1;
}
```

so if you use `i= i-2` or `i-=2` it will decrement `i's` value by 2

```
for(int i = n; i>0; i-=2){
// i = i - 2;
}
```